# App is showing gradle error before connecting to android app

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I was using Firebase as I was new into the firebase whenever I try to connect my app with firebase it shows me error. **Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle build issues and/or resync.**. I had tried to change my sdkversion from 32 to 31 but it was showing different error after that **The minCompileSdk (32) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)** . So, if someone knows the answer please let me know. I have stucked in this for a while now

This is my gradle(App) file

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.login_firebase"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    compileSdkVersion 32
    buildToolsVersion '32.0.0'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Would you mind showing the error that you're trying to resolve?

Comment: The lines that are bold above are the errors : Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle build issues and/or resync

Comment: What you've provided is not enough to understand the problem as a whole, especially since you talk about two approaches in one same paragraph.  Some more information would be ideal before attempting to fix what is still an unknown error to me.